# PHP Code Returns Error Code 500. What's Wrong?

Tags: php, android, database, sql-update, android-volley

I recently made a PHP file to update a database. I use this file in a StringRequest in an android app. Please note that I know Error Code 500 is a server error. My problem is that I cannot figure out what's wrong with the code. Can someone help me understand what's going on?

My code:

```
<?php

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];
    $lastDayName = $_POST["lastDayName"];

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    $con = mysqli_connect("website.com", "username", "password", "dbname");

    switch($location) {
        case "1":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName1=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName2=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", "", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "2":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName2=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName3=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", "", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "3":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName3=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName4=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", "", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "4":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName4=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName5=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", "", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "5":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName5=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName6=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", "", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "6":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName6=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName7=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", "", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "7": /* I don't think this one will be used because it is the last location anyway */
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName7=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        default:
            $response["success"] = false;
            break;
    }

    $con = null;
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Check apache errors at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and post the relevant error message/s.

Comment: The website is hosted from another website and I cannot access these files, if they even use apache.

Comment: If you navigate to the script in your browser, do you get any error messages displayed there? If not, try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);` to get them, then add them to your post as this will help us figure out what is going wrong with your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];
    $lastDayName = $_POST["lastDayName"];

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    $con = mysqli_connect("website.com", "username", "password", "dbname");

    $null_value = "";

    switch($location) {
        case "1":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName1=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName2=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $null_value, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "2":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName2=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName3=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $null_value, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "3":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName3=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName4=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $null_value, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "4":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName4=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName5=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $null_value, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "5":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName5=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName6=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $null_value, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "6":
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName6=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);

            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName7=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $null_value, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        case "7": /* I don't think this one will be used because it is the last location anyway */
            $update_statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE location SET lastDayName7=? WHERE username=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_statement, "ss", $lastDayName, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_statement);
            mysqli_stmt_close($update_statement);
            $response["success"] = true;
            break;
        default:
            $response["success"] = false;
            break;
    }

    $con = null;
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

[php](/questions/tagged/php)[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)[json](/questions/tagged/json)[[image]android](/questions/tagged/android)[sql-update](/questions/tagged/sql-update)[database](/questions/tagged/database)[android-volley](/questions/tagged/android-volley)

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue. I guess I cannot directly use `""` in my PHP code.